# registerNavigationRoute: precached index.html is not updated NetworkFirst

Tags: javascript, service-worker, workbox, workbox-webpack-plugin

**Context**

I have a SPA that use webpack, vueJS and Workbox. In the service-worker, I have the following lines ():

```
workbox.precaching.precache([
  '/index.html'
])

workbox.routing.registerNavigationRoute('/index.html', {
  blacklist: [
    /.*\.css/,
    /.*\.(?:png|jpg|jpeg|svg|gif)/,
    /.*\.(?:js|woff|woff2|otf|ttf)(?:$|\?)/
  ]
})
```

**Problem**

When the app is built for the first time, the `app.js` file is now named `app.xxxxxxxx.js` (for example). So, when the client use the service worker, it precache the `index.html` file with the following line inside:

`<script type=text/javascript src=/js/app.xxxxxxxx.js></script>`

when I update the app and rebuild it, the `app.js` file will be named `app.yyyyyyyy.js` and will BUT the client still have the `index.html` file cached using the old `app.xxxxxxxx.js` file so the app won't work (obviously...)

**Expected behavior**

The service worker seems to get the precached file `index.html` using a CacheFirst strategy. I guess it will work if it use a NetworkFirst strategy.

Is it possible to do it ?

**- EDIT -**

I forgot to precise: each `.js` file is cached using a NetworkFirst strategy:

```
workbox.routing.registerRoute(
  /.*\.(?:js|woff|woff2|otf|ttf)(?:$|\?)/,
  workbox.strategies.networkFirst({
    cacheName: 'assets-cache',
    plugins: [
      new workbox.expiration.Plugin({})
    ],
  })
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [`workbox-webpack-plugin`](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-webpack-plugin) to automatically take a "snapshot" of your local `webpack` assets, and have it generate a the "precache manifest" of all the files that ends up passed in to `workbox.precaching.precache([])`.

This ensures that whenever your `index.html` is redeployed, Workbox will update the previously cached entry. I'd recommend reading [this material](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/get-started) about how precaching behaves.

(When you access your site via a `http://localhost` URL, there should be an error message logged in the JS console in your browser warning about this when you have entries in your precache manifest that appear to be entered "by hand". This is easy to miss, though.)

Comment: I do use the `workbox-webpack-plugin`.
I don't get the point, do you mean that I don't have to `workbox.precaching.precache(['/index.html'])` and only use `workbox.routing.registerNavigationRoute('/index.html')` ?